# How to stack (None,1024) tensor into (None,7,7,1024) tensor in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I have a tensor `A` of shape `(None,1024)` and I want to repeat it 49 times to make a matrix tensor of shape `(None,7,7,1024)`. Every `(,1024)` vector is a copy of the tensor `A`.

How do I do this?

I tried

```
A = K.stack([A,A,A,A,A,A,A])
A = K.stack([A,A,A,A,A,A,A])
```

But this gives me a tensor of shape `(7, 7, None, 1024)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use [`RepeatVector`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#repeatvector) layer to repeat it for 49 times, then use [`Reshape`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#reshape) layer to reshape it as desired:

```
r_A = RepeatVector(49)(A)
rsh_A = Reshape((7, 7, -1))(r_A)
```

Alternatively, you can define a function based on backend functions and wrap it inside a `Lambda` layer:

```
from keras import backend as K

def rsh(x):
    y = K.repeat(x, 49)
    return K.reshape(y, (-1, 7, 7, K.int_shape(y)[-1]))

rsh_A = Lambda(rsh)(A)
```